# sed calculations

Tags: regex, sed

I want to parse a css file and multiply each pixel value by (2/3).  I was wondering if this was possible with sed?  I know this is incorrect syntax but i think it'll bring home the explanation of what i want to achieve:

```
sed -e "s|\([0-9]*\)px|int((\1 * 2)/3)|g" file.css
```

So basically I want to take \1, multiply it by (2/3) and cast to and int.  Or maybe it's more possible with awk?  Suppose I could write a python script, but would like to know if it can be done by quicker means.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use awk

```
$ cat file
foo: 3px; bar: 6px

$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^[0-9]+px/){o=$i;sub(/^[0-9]+/,"",o);$i=($i+0)*(2/3)o}}}1' file
foo: 2px; bar: 4px
```

Comment: It doesn't work on `foo:3px`, which *is* valid CSS.  But as long as you don't write junk like that, you're fine :D  @tomh `-vCONVFMT=%d` will make sure the numbers are truncated to integers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use perl do it like this:

```
echo -e "100px;\n20px;" | perl -pe 's{ (\d*) (?=px) }{ $1*(2/3) }xe'
```

Comment: this does not work if more than one occurrences on a line

Answer (score 0):

To answer the initial question: Yes, you can do this in sed, and No, you do NOT want to do it unless you have some bizarre set of constraints that prevent you from using any other tool.

I say this because the unix dc command (a desktop calculator) has been written in sed, but it works IIRC by performing math the same way you were probably taught math in school: string manipulations on digits, along with carries and such.

You would actually have to write multiply and divide commands (or strip them out of dc.sed) to be able to accomplish this and the results would run a couple of orders of magnitude slower than any of the above suggestions.

In case you're now curious about dc.sed, its usually provided as one of the examples in any sed distribution.

Comment: Overview: http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/scripts/dc_overview.htm Script: http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/scripts/dc.sed

Answer (score 0):

```
sed $( sed -rn '
    :X
    /([0-9]+)px/ {
        s##\a\1\a#
        h
        s#.*\a(.*)\a.*#echo -e s/\1px/$((\1 * 2/3))px/g#ep
        x
        bX
    }
    ' cssfile ) cssfile
```